# SSRS 2008 - Expand and Collapse subreports

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am dealing learning SSRS 2008. I want to do a report that is a little bit more complex.
I would like to have a row with information about "Object": name, id, description, etc. And I would like to have a + sign in this row, so I can expand/collapse rows that are regarding "Comments" about that object, with columns like "comment", "date", etc.

I first tried the "Grouping" approach, but I got to a dead end because the groups would use the same header.
Now I am trying to tackle it with a subreport.

The first problem I had is that I couldn't find the query designer in VS2008, so I started the SQL Reporter Builder.
Is there any way to use the Query Designer inside VS2008?

Then I created my report and my subreport as different report files, because I thought I would be able to use the subreport properties to select the subreport file and add it, but I was wrong. How can I add it? Do I have to publish it?

I just found out that I can't use the rdl file from SQL Report Builder in Visual Studio (it doesn't recognize the file extension, in VS2008 it is rdlc).

I am basically lost.
Could someone give me some guidance?

Thanks,
Oscar

Answer (score 0):

This was asked a while ago but you haven't closed the question so I assume you still need an answer.... Are you looking to add the drill down feature to your report?

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/creating-a-basic-drilldown-report-in-ssr-2005 
http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2009/08/creating-drill-down-report-with-sql.html

If not... I am confused at what you are looking for and if what you want is really intended to be done in SSRS.

And... are you using subreports because the Object information and the Comment information is on different servers or data sources?  Because it seems like you would want to use grouping for this, and group by the objectID and have the comments below.